# Prepopulate Realm database with many to many relationships?

Tags: swift, csv, database-design, realm

I'm brand new to this, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious or not asking the right question. I plan to make an app that have a few sets of data that require many-to-many relationships. For example, if I have a model for **Food** items and a model for **CookingMethod**s to cook that food item. So, each **Food** can have multiple **CookingMethod**s, and each **CookingMethod** applies to multiple types of **Food**.

I *think* this is the right way to set up the realm data:

```
class Food: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = "" 
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0

    var cookingMethods = List<CookingMethod>()
}

class CookingMethod: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""

    let foods = LinkingObjects(fromType: Food.self, property: "cookingMethods")
}
```

Is it now possible to import a set of data (probably a csv file?) using either Realm Studio or programmatically that allows me to link this relationship? The Food would have a list of CookingMethods, and the CookingMethods would link back to multiple different Foods?

If I'm going about this all wrong please let me know, there is a spreadsheet of data that I'd like to add to my app's database as a one time thing.

Comment: This is a well formatted and thought out question so upvote for that. Your code is totally on point and will do exactly what you are expecting. As far as importing files, you *can* do that in Realm Studio but the ability to link data and create relationships will be a bit limited. I would suggest writing the code to do the importing - with that, you can create your FoodItem objects, the child CookingMethod objects and then assign them to the FoodItem cookingMethods property and saving. We use that technique on a very large 2GB file that is imported on a regular basis.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the comment! I found a tutorial that might help with the importing, but am I correct in assuming that I can't assign the relationships using the spreadsheet, for example as an array or cell of comma values?

Comment: Not sure I can answer that question without seeing how the spreadsheet is laid out or how the cells are set up. However, if it's a csv as mentioned in the question that's a different thing so again, hard to answer.